# WordPress :: add_action inside plugin shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a add_action call but only on page that holds a specific plugin shortcode.

At the moment I am getting it at the all around pages and not only on a page that I need.

```
class SomePlugin {
  public __construct() {
    add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'addMetatags'));
  }

  public function addMetatags() {
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article" ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some diging found the best (generic) solution for me:

```
class somePluginClass {    

    public function __construct()
    {
       add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'renderTags'));
    }

    public function renderTags() {
       global $post;
       if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, self::SHORT_CODE)) {
          echo '<meta property="[some-property]" content="[content]" />';
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
class SomePlugin {
  public function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'addMetatags'));
  }

  public function addMetatags() {
    if ( is_page( 'about-me' ) ) { 
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
    }
  }
}
$SomePlugin = new SomePlugin();
```

Comment: Is possible to get something more generic ? Since I know what is the shortcode.

Comment: Us specific page condition like above

Comment: I used it and it works, but just say if is possible to check current page for currently active shortcode on current post and than set the meta. I don't find anything to get those info.

Answer (score 0):

Just use shortcode_exists function.

```
   <?php
add_action('init','prefix_check_short_code');

 function prefix_check_short_code() {
  if ( shortcode_exists( 'your_short_code' ) ) { 
         $SomePlugin = new SomePlugin();
    }
 } 
  ?>
```

Use this code into theme functions or main plugin file.

Function URL on wordpress website is : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists

Comment: It does not work. Plugin is always registered, I need something that will put an action when an plugin shortcode is appeared in post.

Comment: It's still not ok, the main problem of your solution is use of shortcode_exists( 'your_short_code' ) since in it's source check all registered shortcodes, not only on this page but all active shortcodes this will cause that it will execute always.